# Defining two classes inside a class, and accessing its members

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm trying to access members of a classC from classB, both classC and classB are inside classA. Here is what I'm trying to do;

```
            //hello.h
            class hello{
                public:
                   hello();
                   class letters{
                      public:
                         letters();
                         void setName(char n);
                         char getName();
                      private:
                         char name;
                   }
                   class sayHi{
                       public:
                          sayHi();
                          void onJoin();
                   }
            }

            //hello.cpp

            hello::hello(){}
            hello::letters(){}
            hello::sayHi(){}

            void hello::letters::setName(char n){
             hello::letters::name = n;   //trying to access the private variable 'name' inside class letters
            }

            char hello::letters::getName(){
             return hello::letters::name = n; 
            }

            void hello::sayHi::onJoin(){
             cout<< hello::letters::getName() <<endl;
            }
```

I know i'm doing it wrong, am I supposed to create instances of each class and call the members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to create instances of the classes.
These are frequently called "objects", which is why they call it "object-oriented programming".

First, your `getName` and `setName` should look like this:

```
void hello::letters::setName(char n) {
    name = n;
}

char hello::letters::getName() const { // Declaration should also say "const".
    return name; 
}
```

With that out of the way, any `sayHi` instance needs to know which `letters` to say "Hi" to, which means that you need to tell it.
This is usually done by passing a parameter to the method that needs to know:

```
class sayHi{
public:
    sayHi();
    void onJoin(const letters& who)
    {
        cout << who.getName() << endl;
    }
};
```

which you would use somewhat like this:

```
int main()
{
    hello::letters letter;
    letter.setName('p');
    hello::sayHi greeter;
    greeter.onJoin(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ? where have you created objects for accessing these methods ? Also

```
return hello::letters::name = n;
```

this line is wrong, it should be

```
return hello::letters::name;
```